# Wifi Direct - This device address not work on android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I use this method to get the MAC address of my device. This works well in Android 9 and below. But in Android 10, the MAC address is not given correctly and it gives this value every time: `02: 00: 00: 00: 00: 00`

```
public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    switch (action) {
     
        case WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION:

            WifiP2pDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);

            Log.i("My device wifi direct Mac address", device.deviceAddress);

            break;
     }
}
}
```

Comment: [It is supposed to be random](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#data-ids). Regardless, you are not supposed to have access to the MAC address, unless your app is a device owner app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public String getWFDMacAddress() {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface ntwInterface : interfaces) {

                if (ntwInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p2p0")) {
                    byte[] byteMac = ntwInterface.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (byteMac == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : byteMac) {
                        strBuilder.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
                    }

                    if (strBuilder.length() > 0) {
                        strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length() - 1);
                    }

                    return strBuilder.toString();
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```